# How to save the python code in command prompt?

Tags: python-3.8

I've typed a python code that calculates GST in command prompt and  I want to save the code now.
As I'm using command prompt for the first time but unable to save the code. I've searched ways to save it but can't find solution to it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow; it's always nice to see people learning to code, but this question would be better if you explained some of the things you had searched for and what you have tried. Perhaps also copy the 'random python code' in your answer and explain what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to save it as a python file and then call the script.

Assuming python is already installed, put your code in `filename.py`

Eg: `print('Hello World!')`

Then `cd` to the folder and type `python filename.py`

But you might want to check out jupyter notebooks

https://jupyter.org/